# Is it possible to import user32.dll to monodevelop project?

Tags: c#, winapi, mono

I am going to convert c# winform project to monodevelop project, so that the output exe can be opened with mono in linux and Mac OS too. But while I am running the application with mono on ubuntu, I found this error.

`System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetSystemMenu`

I know that this is because of the user32.dll. I tried to import it to my new monoproject, but couldn't find a solution. I know that the function `GetSystemMenu` is WINAPI function, but I think there will be some way to use it in monodevelop on ubuntu. I really want to know about the solution. It will be a great help if anyone tell me a solution. thanks.

Comment: *user32.dll* is part of Windows. It can only execute on Windows. There is no equivalent in any other OS (including Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function, in this library, exists only on Windows. The code would appear to be performing platform specific user interface operations. They would need to be recoded to target each different platform. Or, if possible, replaced with platform independent code.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your explanation. It is impossible to use 'user32.dll' in any other platforms. I have found the alternative way, Thanks.